# Cannot live connect to SSAS tabular but can do the import

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have installed SSAS tabular(2019) on my laptop and Power BI desktop (September 2021)
I make a project and deploy then I can see it in the SSMS when I connect to the analysis service. In power bi when I choose import I can see the model but when choosing the live connect it gives the error "The server you are trying to connect does not have any model or you don't have permission to access them".
As I search the net the result is because of the access permission. but I run the power bi as an administrator. I don't know which access is required and how I can check it.
can you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're running SSMS elevated, and you haven't added your individual account as an Analysis Services administrator.

Comment: How I can add my account as an Analysis Service administrator? I have added a role to the model and my login account to the laptop and  NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT

Comment: Read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/grant-server-admin-rights-to-an-analysis-services-instance?view=asallproducts-allversions#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20use%20SQL%20Server%20Management%20Studio,of%20or%20select%20Entire%20directory%20and%20click%20Ok.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the steps but the account was added before and yet the problem exists